# Unauthorization in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Can someone tell me why after loggedin to system, in `Postman` response i get `401 - unauthorization` instead of my `token`?

CorsConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter(){
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
//        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
//        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
//        config.addAllowedMethod("*");

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(securityUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
//                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/api/user/register/**", "/api/user/namecheck/**", "/api/password/**")
//                .permitAll()
//                .antMatchers("/api/user/checkUsernameAvailability", "/api/user/checkEmailAvailability")
//                .permitAll()
                //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/polls/**", "/api/users/**")
                //    .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.headers().cacheControl();

    }
}
```

AuthController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody AuthRequest request){
        Object principal;
        Object credentials;
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword()
                ));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }
}
```

AuthenticatedUser.java, my model

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class AuthenticatedUser implements UserDetails {

    private UUID id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String token;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    public AuthenticatedUser(){}

    public static AuthenticatedUser mapFromEntity(UserEntity userEntity){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userEntity.getRole().name()));

        return new AuthenticatedUser()
                .setId(userEntity.getId())
                .setEmail(userEntity.getEmail())
                .setPassword(userEntity.getPassword())
                .setFirstName(userEntity.getFirstName())
                .setLastName(userEntity.getLastName())
                .setAuthorities(authorities);
    }


    private Collection<? extends  GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }
```

TokenProvider.java

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    @Value("${jwt.salt}")
    private String jwtSalt;

    @Value("${jwt.expiry}")
    private int jwtExpiry;

    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        AuthenticatedUser userEntity = (AuthenticatedUser) authentication.getPrincipal();

        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + jwtExpiry);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(userEntity.getId().toString())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSalt)
                .compact();
    }

    public UUID getUserIdFromJWT(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(jwtSalt)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return UUID.fromString(claims.getSubject());
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
///
```

JwtauthenticationFilter.java

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserDetailsService securityUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(request);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                UUID userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);
                UserDetails userDetails = securityUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot login (nor should you with such a controller as that is bypassing Spring Security features). So your controller isn't being used (or at least cannot be used) and the stuff that you need needs to be in your `JwtAuthenticationFilter` (and not a controller).

Comment: @M.Deinum I add ```JwtauthenticationFilter``` at the bottom, can you show me how it should be?

Comment: You either need to add the login part to your filter OR allow all access to `/api/auth`. Although I would recommend against using a controller for authentication with Spring Security (as you are now working around Spring Security instead of better integrating withit).

Comment: still don't work for me :/

Comment: This question doesn’t seem to have anything to do with CORS. If you’re getting a 401 in Postman, that’s not related to CORS.

Comment: @Piotrek refer this repository https://github.com/nikhilmalavia/SpringBootJWT

Answer (score 0):

You should /api/auth route to the SecurityConfig

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/",
                    "/api/auth",
                    "/favicon.ico",
                    "/**/*.png",
                    "/**/*.gif",
                    "/**/*.svg",
                    "/**/*.jpg",
                    "/**/*.html",
                    "/**/*.css",
                    "/**/*.js")
            .permitAll()
            .authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.headers().cacheControl();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't comment, I'm writing it here.
Make sure like @Pankratiew Alexandr said to add `/api/auth` endpoint with `permitAll()`.
Then my question is if you have any user already in your memory or database. I mean that when you call method `authenticateUser` in your controller you use `authenticationManager.authenticate(...`, so `loadByUsername()` is called and it may don't load any user with provided e-mail and password.